# Dividing speech signal into 10ms non overlapping windows

Tags: java, android, signal-processing

In my application, I need to divide the whole speech signal coming from the mic (after sampling) into 10 ms non-overlapping windows.

I am currently using hanning window in my code in order to do that:

```
public short[] HanningWindow(short[] signal_in, int pos, int size)
    {
for (int i = pos; i < pos + size; i++)
{
    int j = i - pos; // j = index into Hann window function
    signal_in[i] = (short) (signal_in[i] * 0.5 * (1.0 - Math.cos(2.0 * Math.PI * j / size)));
}
return signal_in;
   }
```

Now my question is,,, where do i specify that i need 10ms non-overlapping windows?

Comment: If you're using a window function (e.g. Hanning), it's unlikely that non-overlapping windows is what you need...

Comment: actually i want to implement Mahalanobis Distance algorithm on a signal and this need to Divide the whole speech signal into 10 ms 
non-overlapping windows ,,my question is how can i improve my code to do that ???@Oli Charlesworth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just break your signal up into chunks of Fs * 0.01 samples, e.g. if your sample rate Fs = 44.1 kHz then you would process successive blocks of 4410 samples. You can then apply your window function, FFT, etc to each block of 441 samples.

Comment: thanks @Paul R ...am working on Mahalanobis Distance algorithm  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.138.623&rep=rep1&type=pdf                             where i need firstly divide the signal into 1600 samples and then divide the whole speech signal into 10 ms non-overlapping windows ...iam using 8000 HZ sample rate so should i divide the signal into 1600 and then divide each 1600 samples to 80 sample???

Comment: Yes, for Fs = 8 kHz you need 80 samples for 10 ms. So your block of 1600 samples can be divided into 20 non-overlapping windows of 10 ms each.